# DNS records list

Tags: list, powershell, dns, export, dump

I am trying to get a list of all machines that have an A record on a certain DNS server (company's internal network DNS).

So far I managed to either get all hosts that are online using NMAP and giving it a specific subnet to scan (nmap -sN [subnet]), but unfortunately it crashes fairly often when I give it a subnet bigger than /24. Of course the other option is to ping all IPs in a given range and see who answers but that takes way too long.

I am trying to include this in a powershell script, so anything that is runnable from a CLI would be great, anything in any programming language that I can compile and run from CLI would be good, anything requiring manual input, not so great..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: if at all possible it would be great to limit the list to a single zone.

Comment: What point did I miss?
I read the FAQ and, going in order:
Research: obviously done since I described trying with nmap and why it's not why I want;
What I've tried: see above;
Language and platform: Powershell 3.0, platform Windows Client and Server;
Code: question does not include code (small snippet from nmap documentation);
Locale specific info: I do not believe that's relevant;
Formatting spelling and grammar: no mistakes I can see;
Is anything unclear about the question? Or is there some other point I did not consider?

Comment: Question was purposefully broad because I am looking for any viable solution, as I explain in paragraph 3.
Google isn't really helpful and I'm unfortunately no DNS expert. My research has brought up the 2 work-arounds that I described but neither is the kind of solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to powershell, not amazingly automated but you could use something in the DNS client cmdlet.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590772.aspx

Get-Help  -Examples

Comment: Uhm, looks interesting but apparently that would only allow me to get the list of DNS records in the local client's cache, or am I reading the page wrong?

Then again the  Get-DnsServerResourceRecord cmdlet seems promising even though it only runs on Win 8 or Server 2012..

Answer (score 0):

Please use this powerfull GridView:

```
$server = "Your_DNS_Server"
$record = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\MicrosoftDNS" -ComputerName $server -Class MicrosoftDNS_AType
$record | Select DomainName,RecordData,OwnerName | Sort-Object -Property {[System.Version]$_.RecordData} | Out-GridView
```